# Script to SUM Values

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Can you help me please?

I want a script to sum rows after a name change.

Something like this:

```
COLUMN A           - COLUMN B    - COLUMN C - COLUMN D - COLUMN E
aa                 - aa          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€
aa                 - aa          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€
aa                 - aa          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€
bb                 - bb          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€
bb                 - bb          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€
```

I want this:

```
COLUMN A           - COLUMN B - COLUMN C - COLUMN D - COLUMN E
aa                 - aa          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€
aa                 - aa          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€
aa                 - aa          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€
blank              blank         - 15€      - 15€      - 15€
blank              blank         blank      blank      blank  
bb                 - bb          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€  
bb                 - bb          - 5€       - 5€       - 5€
blank              blank         - 10€      - 10€      - 10€
blank              blank         blank      blank      blank
```

PS:I am in the financial area, but with a great passion for the computer area, but unfortunately, I am not that good in this area, so I asked for your help.

Comment: will the entries in column A be as ordered as your example suggests or will they be randomly placed in the column (so a mix of aa and bb etc) and will the descriptor always be in the same format in both column A and B and throughout column A (ie not "aa" sometimes and "aaa" others meaning a free format of input)?

Comment: hi, they will be ordered by name. Sometimes i have AAA, BB. Its not a fixed number of same name. Thanks

Comment: Well, as a starter, would an in-cell dropdown list help to regularise what is allowed in column A seehttps://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en ?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. You might find helpful to start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Answer (score 0):

You have transaction data including three currency/value fields. The total number of rows, and the number of transactions for each user/customer is unknown and can vary.

This key facets of this script are:

- create a temporary array (`temparray`) to capture row values
- create a second array (`targetarray`) to accumulate row values, and to enable a single "write" command to update the output sheet.
- loop through the rows:

  - test for the first row (there are no previous values)
  - test for a change in name

    - if no chnage, continue to accumulate totals
    - if change, then add totals to the array, zero the "total" variables, add the values for the new line.
- after the loop,

  - add the totals for the last name.
  - Update the output range

---

```
function dataview() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sourcesheetname = "source";
  var source = ss.getSheetByName(sourcesheetname);
  var targetsheetname = "output";
  var target = ss.getSheetByName(targetsheetname);
  
  // get the number of rows of information
  var LR = source.getLastRow();
  
  // get the range and the values
  var sourcerange = source.getRange(1, 1, LR, 5);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the range is "+sourcerange.getA1Notation());
  var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();
  
  // create variables for processing
  var targetarray = []; // array for cumulative data
  var totalC = 0;
  var totalD = 0;
  var totalE = 0;

  // loop through the rows
  for (var i=0;i<sourcevalues.length;i++){
    
    // set a temporary array for row data
    var temparray = [];
      
    // is this first row
    if (i==0){
      
      // build the line array
      temparray.push(sourcevalues[i][0],sourcevalues[i][1],sourcevalues[i][2],sourcevalues[i][3],sourcevalues[i][4]);
      // update the targetarray
      targetarray.push(temparray);
      // update the totals
      totalC = totalC + sourcevalues[i][2];
      totalD = totalC + sourcevalues[i][3];
      totalE = totalC + sourcevalues[i][4];
      
    } else{

      // not the first row, so check the names
      var thisname = sourcevalues[i][0];
      var lastname = sourcevalues[i-1][0];

      // is this a new name - No
      if (thisname ==lastname){ 
        // same name
        
        // build the line array
        temparray.push(sourcevalues[i][0],sourcevalues[i][1],sourcevalues[i][2],sourcevalues[i][3],sourcevalues[i][4]);
        // update the targetarray
        targetarray.push(temparray);
        // update the totals
        totalC = totalC + sourcevalues[i][2];
        totalD = totalC + sourcevalues[i][3];
        totalE = totalC + sourcevalues[i][4];
      }
      else{
        
        // is this a new name - Yes
        
        // populate the subototal line
        temparray.push("","",totalC, totalD,totalE);
        // update the targetarray
        targetarray.push(temparray);
        // reset the temparray
        temparray = [];
        // reset the totals
        var totalC = 0;
        var totalD = 0;
        var totalE = 0;
        
        // populate the blank line
        temparray.push("","","", "","");
        // update the targetarray
        targetarray.push(temparray);
        // reset the temparray
        temparray = [];
        
        // build the line array
        temparray.push(sourcevalues[i][0],sourcevalues[i][1],sourcevalues[i][2],sourcevalues[i][3],sourcevalues[i][4]);
        // update the targetarray
        targetarray.push(temparray);
        // reset the totals
        totalC = totalC + sourcevalues[i][2];
        totalD = totalC + sourcevalues[i][3];
        totalE = totalC + sourcevalues[i][4];
        
      }
    }
  } //end of loop
  
  // add the final subtotal
  // reset the temparray
  temparray = [];
  // populate the subototal line
  temparray.push("","",totalC, totalD,totalE);
  // update the targetarray
  targetarray.push(temparray);
  // reset the temparray
  temparray = [];
  // populate the blank line
  temparray.push("","","", "","");
  // update the targetarray
  targetarray.push(temparray);

  // define the target range
  var targetrange = target.getRange(1, 1, targetarray.length, 5)
  // update for the source values
  targetrange.setValues(targetarray)
  return false;
}
```